# Qual a diferença entre innerHTML e appendChild no JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Qual a diferença entre `innerHTML` e o `appendChild`? Na minha opinião são muito parecidos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), um método, adiciona um novo elemento ao DOM, portanto é uma ação sendo executada com a clara intenção de expandir o DOM criando um filho para um elemento já existente, não importa o que está adicionando, mas precisa ser um elemento válido. Quando fizer isto, dependendo do que for colocado poderá mudar a forma de visualização do documento.

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), uma propriedade, permite você acessar o valor contido dentro de um elemento do DOM e este valor pode ser um texto qualquer, em alguns casos esse pode fazer sentido para o DOM e ele ser considerado um novo elemento. Talvez o que queira saber é a diferença para o uso de `innerHTML +=`, porque aí, apesar de diferentes tem alguma semelhança, ainda assim é um pouco diferente porque ele não adiciona algo novo pura e simplesmente, ele substitui o que já existia por algo novo, então também há uma destruição. Neste caso você está trocando um texto existente por um texto qualquer (pode conter HTML) que pode fazer sentido para o DOM e isto alteraria a forma como o documento é mostrado.

Se não for um texto simples (sem semântica específico para o HTML) eu considero uma bela gambiarra, é menos robusto porque ele aceita tudo, até um HTML mal formado; e menos performático porque ele reconstrói todo o DOM para tentar garantir que tudo está ok, então me parece um trabalho monumental; e ainda é menos seguro, boa parte do ataques de injeção de HTML são feitos por causa disto.

Então me parece mais uma dessas coisas que as pessoas usam sem critério só porque viu em algum lugar alguém fazendo isso e a pessoa não se preocupou em entender para o que ele deve ser usado (por isso a pergunta é boa). Claro que em casos de troca de um conteúdo por outro pode ser simples fazer isto. Mas porque você trocaria o HTML? Trocar o texto contido dele, mudar uma propriedade com outro método em JavaScript eu entendo, mas trocar o HTML? Raro isso fazer sentido, quase todos casos que vejo o uso é a pessoa tentando consertar uma uma decisão errada anterior ou desconhecimento de como essas coisas funcionam.

Tem mais algumas implicações em usar essa bomba, acho que vai além do que perguntou e não sou a pessoa mais indicada para falar de tudo.

Considere também o uso de [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) e [`createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) para algumas situações.

## Teste de performance

Só para exemplificar como há uma boa diferença de performance rode isto:

```js
var mainNodeInner = document.createElement('div'),
    mainNodeInnerPlus = document.createElement('div'),
    mainNodeAppend = document.createElement('div'),
    sampleHTML = '<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>',
    testHTML = '',
    numSamples = 1000,
    before = null,
    after = null;
for (var i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) testHTML += sampleHTML;
mainNodeInnerPlus.innerHTML = testHTML;
before = new Date().getTime();
mainNodeInnerPlus.innerHTML += sampleHTML;
after = new Date().getTime();
console.log("TIME INNER HTML +=: " + (after - before) + " ms");
console.log("Num childs after: " + mainNodeInnerPlus.childElementCount);
console.log(' ');
var allHTML = testHTML + sampleHTML;
before = new Date().getTime();
mainNodeInner.innerHTML = allHTML;
after = new Date().getTime();
console.log("TIME INNER HTML =: " + (after - before) + " ms");
console.log("Num childs after: " + mainNodeInner.childElementCount);
console.log(' ');
mainNodeAppend.innerHTML = testHTML;
before = new Date().getTime();
var sampleNode = document.createElement('div');
sampleNode.innerHTML = sampleHTML;
while (sampleNode.hasChildNodes()) mainNodeAppend.appendChild(sampleNode.firstChild);
after = new Date().getTime();
console.log("TIME APPEND CHILD: " + (after - before) + " ms");
console.log("Num childs after: " + mainNodeAppend.childElementCount);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/CompareInnerHTMLAppendChild.js).

[Fonte](https://gist.github.com/oliverfernandez/5619180).

[Veja outro teste no seu navegador](https://jsperf.com/insertadjacenthtml-vs-innerhtml-vs-appendchild) (pode variar de acordo com a implementação).