# Onde está o erro no código do ano bissexto?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com duvida aonde eu errei nesse código aonde o usuário digita um ano e aparece na tela se aquele ano é ou não bissexto.

```js
function calcularBissexto() {
  var bi = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bissexto').value);
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');

  for (bi % 4; bi % 100; bi % 400) {
    if (bi % 4 == 0 || bi % 100 == 0 || bi % 400 == 0) {
      msg.innerHTML += 'E bissexto'
    } else {
      msg.innerHTML += 'Nao e bissexto';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="bissexto">
<button onclick="calcularBissexto()">Click</button>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse `for` não faz sentido do ponto de vista de sintaxe ou de lógica, também não faz sentido dar `parseFloat()` para ano, seria algo assim:

```js
function calcularBissexto(ano) {
    return ano % 4 == 0 && ano % 100 != 0 || ano % 400 == 0 ? 'E bissexto' : 'Nao e bissexto';
}
console.log(calcularBissexto(1980));
console.log(calcularBissexto(1981));
console.log(calcularBissexto(1900));
console.log(calcularBissexto(2000));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Leap.js).

Note que eu tirei a lógica que atualiza a página, acostume-se fazer funções que são responsáveis por apenas uma tarefa, esta calcula o bissexto, outra deve cuidar da atualização da página que [nem deveria usar `innerHTML`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/392875/101).

Answer (score 3):

Sei que não foi mencionado, entretanto voce também pode validar se um ano é bissexto ou não com a verificação de dias do mês. Por exemplo:

```js
function calculaAno(){


const getAno = document.getElementById('entradaAno').value;


const AnoBissexto = (ano) => new Date(ano, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1 ? 'bissexto': 'não é bissexto';

const tipoAno = AnoBissexto(getAno);


document.getElementsByClassName('info')[0].innerText = tipoAno;

}
```

```css
form {
 font-family:sans-serif;
 margin-top:1rem;
 margin-left:1rem;
 margin-right:1rem;
}

input.form-control {
 width:200px;
    
 }

div.info { 
 margin-top:1rem;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<form action="">
<label>Digite o ano : </label>
 <input id="entradaAno" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
 
 <div class="info alert alert-link" role="alert">
  Por favor digite o ano válido.
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="calculaAno()" class="btn btn-link">Calcular</button>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your code not worked. You used january on Date and not consider culture. And why are you using const? I tested your code and got errors.

Comment: Primeiro, os meses vao de 0 a 11, segundo e um valor constante , saber se é ou não, portanto const

Comment: Eu perguntei porque eu usei seu código e testei com o ano 2016 e deu ruim (2016 é bisexto), mas quando troquei pra (ano, 2, 29) ai funcionou (com algumas mudanças, pois do jeito que está, na prática deu erro, e está exibindo o seu código invés da mensagem) . 
Seria legal se vc coloca-se um snippet pra mostrar na prática como usar .